# How to read an exe file when it is running in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to read an exe file when it is running as follows:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(assemblyPath, FileMode.Open);
BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
byte[] bin = br.ReadBytes(Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
fs.Close();
```

But an exception raises: The file cannot be accessed because it is occupied by another process.

However, I can copy this file using Windows Explorer. So it is possible to read this file. How can I read it in my program? Thanks!

Comment: Withouth being able to check available options: can't you open the stream with FileMode.Read?

Comment: Have you tried with `FileStream fs = new FileStream(assemblyPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);`?

Comment: @Alberto You should post this as answer (and maybe point out what `FileAccess`/`FileShare` is and what the defaults are)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
FileStream fs = 
    new FileStream(assemblyPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
```

The [FileShare.Read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileshare.aspx) flag is the key, it controls the kind of access other FileStream objects can have to the same file.